# "Can't embed object in code" error for UTF-8 constant in Clojure

Tags: clojure, constants

I want to keep a constant around to represent the UTF-8 Charset.

```lisp
(java.nio.charset.Charset/forName "UTF-8")
; #<UTF_8 UTF-8>
(def ^:const utf-8 (java.nio.charset.Charset/forName "UTF-8"))
; #'user/utf-8
utf-8
; #<UTF_8 UTF-8>
```

But when I use it, I get an error:

```
(type utf-8)
; CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't embed object in code, maybe print-dup not defined: UTF-8, compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:1:1)
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will work if `:const` is not used in the `def`:

```clj
(def utf-8 (java.nio.charset.Charset/forName "UTF-8"))
; #'user/utf-8
(type utf-8)
; sun.nio.cs.UTF_8
```

Why? This [answer to "Why can't I use Clojure's :^const with ..."](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13111273/109618) is useful.

Still, but I'd like to find something more detailed and/or authoritative. I'd also be interested to see if there is a way to improve how Clojure handles `:const` for the above case.

Comment: The relevant text is “compile-time values have to be printable and readable (by the clojure reader)” but the linked answer doesn't clearly state _why_ that is so. I have my suspicions, but I'm not a Clojure user…

Comment: :const is only for primitives. It may pretend to do something for non-primitives but it only does what it implies for primitive data. It is not about the immutability of the thing, but replacing references with the actual value. This only makes sense for unboxed values, AKA primitives.